# GeoJSON Vector Tiling in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

I'd like to implement a geojson file with over 30MB in a web map. Of course, the Web Map runs very slow, when importing it directly. So I came across the pluginn geojson-vt, but I can't get it working. I'm just too unexperienced in Leaflet to get this done.

What would be the way to get this working?

I tried it with this code from the [GitHub Pag](https://github.com/brandonxiang/leaflet-geojson-vt/tree/leaflet1.0.0)e:

```
var options = {
    maxZoom: 16,
    tolerance: 3,
    debug: 0,
    style: {
        fillColor: '#1EB300',
        color: '#F2FF00',
        weight: 2
    }
};
var canvasLayer = L.gridLayer.geoJson("myfile.geojson", options).addTo(map);
```

I have the geojsonFile "myfile.geojson" stored directly in the leaflet folder next to the index.html.

I am running leaflet 1.7.1.

I have loaded the `<script src="https://unpkg.com/geojson-vt@3.2.0/geojson-vt.js"></script>`.

I have stored the leaflet-geojson-vt.js directly in the leaflet folder next to the geojson and loaded it via `<script src="/leaflet-geojson-vt.js"></script>`.

Comment: `L.gridLayer.geoJson` expects GeoJSON object, not a file. You have first to read your GeoJSON file with some of the AJAX methods, as you can see in the demo https://brandonxiang.github.io/leaflet-geojson-vt/test/

Comment: I get the idea. So, I tried to load in the geojson with  'var myfile = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("myfile.geojson",{style:Style});'  and to call the variable myfile with 'var canvasLayer = L.gridLayer.geoJson(myfile, options).addTo(map);'  But it still doesn't display.

Comment: No, that's not the right way. With `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` you get Leaflet vector layer, not GeoJSON object. Google for JS `fetch` method.

Comment: I tried to find some input I can work with, unfortunately I am still not quite sure how to import it as a object. Is there maybe a usefull hint in the leaflet documentation I have not seen yet?